# refused database connection causes encoding error

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgreSQL Server with some databases. Every user can only connect to certain databases.
So far so good. I wanted to test if everthing worked, so i used pgAdmin III to log in with a restricted user. when i try to connect to a database the user has no connection rights to, something seems to happen to the logfile!
it can't be read by the server-status window anymore. All i get are a lot of messages about invalid Byte-sequences for encoding utf8.
The only way of stopping those messages windows is to kill the programm and force postgre to create a new logfile.

can anyone explain to me why that happens and how i can stop it???

Comment: "something" doesn't happen to the logfile - a set of characters get written to it. (1) What are they? (2) Do you think this is valid UTF-8? (3) If not, does it match some other encoding on your databases or as a default on your system?

Comment: i reproduced the error with a fresh logfile. the only thing that ist written into the logfile is: `FATAL:  keine Berechtigung für Datenbank »DB_2«
DETAIL:  Benutzer hat das CONNECT-Privileg nicht.` which only means the the user does not have the right to connect to the database. afer that there' a lot of '
`FEHLER:  ungÃ¼ltige Byte-Sequenz fÃ¼r Kodierung Â»UTF8Â«: 0xfc` which is the error message i get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think the problem is the "ü" in "für". The error message seems to be complaining about a character code 0xfc which in [latin1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (and similar) is lower case u with umlaut.

Messages sent back via a database connection should be translated to the client encoding. However, the log-file contains output from a variety of sources and [according to this](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/main-log-encoding-problem-td5709590.html) there were issues fairly recently (2012):

> It's a known issue, I'm afraid. The PostgreSQL postmaster logs in the
>   system locale, and the PostgreSQL backends log in whatever encoding
>   their database is in. They all write to the same log file, producing a
>   log file full of mixed encoding data that'll choke many text editors.

So - I'm guessing your system locale is 8859-1 (or -15 perhaps) whereas pg-admin is expecting UTF-8. Short-term, you could set the system encoding to UTF-8, longer term drop a bug report over to the pgadmin team - one error message is helpful, after that it should probably just put hexcodes in the text or some such.

Comment: Thanks a lot! changing the client encoding helped!